# sumif depending on value in row

Tags: vba, excel-formula, google-sheets

I have:

```
A    B        C=unique(A:A)  D=sumif(B:B,"=C",A:A)??
Jim  3        Jim            5                  
Jane 4        Jane           10
Jane 6
Jim  2
```

How do I sum up the B column if the value of A is same as the one in C?

Comment: Value in A is string and D is int, how will they match?

Comment: @OP If an answer worked for you, please mark it as correct. Thanks.

Comment: @gaganshera thanks!  I corrected the question. Meant C. Please C my edit.

Comment: I C what you did there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `SUMIF` function, the syntax is,

`=SUMIF(Range,Criteria,SumRange)`

So your formula in `Column D` should be,

`=SUMIF(A:A,C1,B:B)`

[image]

Comment: Of course!  How stupid can I be. (Its because I'm used  to excel R1C1 and am working in google spreadsheets so didn't see the obvious). 
I then copy the formula to the next rows, and it will correctly show C2 C3 C4 etc.

Comment: @pashute Glad to help you!!

Answer (score 2):

Create a new column `E` where you check if the value in `A` and `D` if the same like `=IF(B2=D2,B2,0)`.
Then do a sum of that `E` row like `=SUM(F2:F10)` to get the sum of all the matched values.

Comment: This answers the question as it was written although it did not make much sense. Thank you @Gaganshera for taking your time, and thank you for notifying me of the mistake. Gowtham Shiva got it right and understood what I was asking.